# Array of types?

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I have several structs, and I want to create an array of them so that I can use its members as an argument for a template, something like `types = {int, float}; multiply<types[i]>();`. It can be done through overloading, but I have lots of functions so this is not a way. As far as I know, we can store types only as pointers (so I'll actually have to dereference it: `multiply<*types[i]>();`), but here I stop to understand because to create a pointer I have to know type of variable it's pointing to, and what is a type of a class (of a type)? I thought "screw it, I'll use auto", but then it seems to be that pointers to different classes are of different types, so that I have to erase their type to store them in a common array, and so on, I have this now:

```
auto types = {std::make_shared<void>(Student), std::make_shared<void>(Citizen)};
```

And it says that `Student` and `Citizen` don't refer to a value.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `std::vector<std::variant<types_that_you_want_too_support_here>>`

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't need array with elements of different types, I need array of types themselves.

Comment: If you really want an array of types, use a `std::tuple` for that.

Comment: @Artyer thank you! Is there a way to do it through array? Because I thought that types of types should be of the same type... and there's no need for `tuple` then.

Comment: @NathanOliver wait, I think about it and now I don't understand how `tuple` can work here. Again it lets me create an array with elements of different types, not of types themselves.

Comment: Please provide some [MRE] in your question, or much more C++ code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convenient built-in array of types in C++ is [`std::tuple<Types...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

To access the ith type in a std::tuple, use [`std::tuple_element_t<i, your_tuple>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element).

For example:

```cpp
using types = std::tuple<int, float>;
multiply<std::tuple_element_t<i, types>>();
```

Types are only "there" at compile time, thus all of your indices need to be at compile time, and you store them in the type information (here the variadic type in `std::tuple`), instead of in a variable.

You can use a helper type to make this less verbose:

```cpp
template<class... Types>
struct type_array {
    using as_tuple = std::tuple<Types...>;

    template<std::size_t I>
    using get = std::tuple_element_t<I, as_tuple>;

    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Types);
};

using types = type_array<int, float>;
multiply<types::get<i>>();
```

Comment: So we create a tuple which we actually don't use, but access its types?

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky We don't construct it, yes. It's just the simplest way to index the parameter pack `Types`.

Comment: "all of your indices need to be at compile time" — sad, I actually needed it at runtime.

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky The types no longer exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> I have several structs, and I want to create an array of them

In C++, **arrays contain *elements* all of the *same [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature)*. At runtime, types have disappeared** since they have been [erased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) (except with [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), related to [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)). So you cannot directly have an array containing elements of *different* types (or don't call that an array).

Please refer to [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and later to the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) for more about C++. You could find the [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) standard too.

It looks that you want some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in C++. Consider then using the standard [`std::variant` template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) from C++17.

If you want a [product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type), use of course `std::tuple` as [answered by Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62139716/841108)

**Take advantage of *existing* C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)**, when they fit your needs. Of course you can combine them with product types, sum types, [strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string), nested containers, [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), etc...

If you cannot use C++17 but just C++11 and need to implement some tagged union, use some anonymous `union` but be aware of the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Consider also using [Boost](https://boost.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) (both provide tagged unions in their own way).

Read also a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), since C++ is a *very* difficult programming language (that I don't claim to master, just to use).

Comment: Can you advise me what I can do in my case then? Because using unions is ineffective here, I guess. I want user to be able to choose what struct they want to work with. Since structs are pretty similar and have same overloaded operators, there are some functions that would work with any struct, so I wanted to do it this way: every such function has a template argument of type, then I ask user what type they want and bind function to it (like `auto new_func = [&] { old_func<types[i]>; }`).

Comment: Maybe I should create an interface for these structs.

Comment: **You need first to use the correct terminology.** Do you want a product type or a tagged union type? Please **edit your question accordingly**, then I could answer it tomorrow morning. Notice that `struct` are the same as `class` (except for `private:` vs `public:` ...). If possible, show some code